# What's wrong with my textbox html code?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Welcome Page </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Greetings</h1>
    <p>
        Enter your name: <input type=“text” id=“nameBox” size=12 value="">
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="Click for Greeting"
        onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML='hello' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + ', welcome to my page.<br>Do you mind if I call you' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + '?';">
    <hr>
    <div id=“outputDiv”></div>
</body>
```

All I'm getting is an error in line 13: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null.

I'm new to this, so help would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, there's a really handy tool to find errors in your HTML: http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 4):

1. You are using smart quotes in your html. Replace “” with "".
2. `size=12`: `12` isn't in quotes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mu4o2sak/1/) (Added spaces before or after some string literals to make output string easier to read.)